# Avogadro law and reactions in a gaseous phase

Tags: reaction-mechanism

When $\pu{100 mL}$ of hydrogen combines with $\pu{50 mL}$ of oxygen, why is $\pu{100 mL}$ of water produced and not $\pu{150 mL}$? As $100+50=150$

I understand that $\ce{2 H2 + O2 -> 2 H2O}$, when we balance the equation. But it is [Avogadro's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro%27s_law) that confuses me here.

Comment: Neither books, neither magazine articles try   to put near all the info to their titles.

Comment: @Poutnik Why, some of them do. _"The Life and Strange Surprizing Adventures of Robinson Crusoe, Of York, Mariner: Who lived Eight and Twenty Years, all alone in an un-inhabited Island on the Coast of America, near the Mouth of the Great River of Oroonoque; Having been cast on Shore by Shipwreck, wherein all the Men perished but himself. With An Account how he was at last as strangely deliver'd by Pyrates."_

Comment: What exactly confuses you?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hehe, You are almost right, but I miss there the recipe for the homemade cheese or pottery for making corn wheat. :-) // Seriously and generally, one should not assume implicit presence of generalisms in statements.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

The Avogadro law says by other words that

*At the same pressure and temperature, the number of gas molecules in the given volume doesn't depend on type of molecules.*

As there are created 2 molecules from 3, the final volume (at the same conditions as initial ones) shrinks to 2/3 of the initial one (assuming the ideal gas behaviour of water vapor with pressure low enough and temperature high enough to prevent vapor condensation).

Comment: Do you (by your background in meteorology) have a reference about the molar volume of water (as gas at STP) at hand to complement the visualization of molar volumes of the elements (https://www.webelements.com/periodicity/molar_volume/) with the one of hydrogen ($\pu{11.42 cm^3/mol}$, [reference](https://www.webelements.com/hydrogen/)), and oxygen ($\pu{17.36 cm^3/mol}$, [reference](https://www.webelements.com/oxygen/))? I speculate this could extend nicely the answer with a paragraph: «However, as real gases at STP (esp. water), the reaction of H and O would instead yield xy mL of water only.

Comment: @Buttonwood Well, water would probably end as liquid water, but you know how these oversimplified school tasks are like.  Real water at STP has molar volume of 1 mol  of liquid water at STP, some 18.0x mL/mol. But if air with saturated vapor partial pressure at STP is considered, It can be very well approximated as ideal gas.

Comment: @Buttonwood I cannot remember we needed vapor molar volume.

Answer (score 0):

$100$ mL gas A + $50$ mL gas B gives $150$ mL total gas if there has not been any chemical reaction between the molecules of the gases, whatever the nature of the gases A and B. If there has been a chemical reaction between them, the volume is not conserved. Only the mass is conserved.